# SQL Server Stored Procedure SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on deciphering some stored procedures and have minimal vocabulary on the subject. Can someone please explain to me what role this '1' serves in the below statement? I can not find any DISTINCT syntax tutorials to explain this. I'm referring to the actual "1" one in the statement.

```
USE TEST
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_F_SQL 
 (@Id int) 
 WITH ENCRYPTION AS  
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.MAP_SQL.rID, 
    dbo.MAP_SQL.lID, 
    dbo.MAP_SQL.cID, 
    **1** as RESPFACT, 
    dbo.MAP_SQL.Longitude, 
    dbo.MAP_SQL.Latitude, 
    dbo.MAP_SQL.Altitude,

...
```

Comment: The 1 just functions as a constant value, nothing more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1` has nothing to do with `DISTINCT`.  It just adds an output column titled `RESPFACT` that has a value of `1` for all rows.  I suspect whatever is *consuming* the output need that column.

`SELECT DISTINCT` only returns the "distinct" rows from the output - meaning rows where ALL column values are equal.

e.g. if your output *without* distinct was

```
1   2   ABC   DEF
2   3   GHI   JLK
2   1   ABC   DEF
1   2   ABC   DEF
```

Then rows 1 and 4 would be seen as "equal" and ony one would be returned:

```
1   2   ABC   DEF
2   3   GHI   JLK
2   1   ABC   DEF
```

Note that rows 1 and 3 are NOT equal even though 3 of the 4 column values match.

Comment: No Understand DISTINCT, what is the 1 for in the statement?

Comment: @Ccorock OK that wasn't clear from the original question - I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `1` generates a column called `RESPFACT`.  This always has the value of `1`.

I cannot say why this is important for the `sp_F_SQL` procedure.

The `distinct` returns unique rows.  If there are duplicate values for the columns in the `select` then only one row is returned.  Clearly, the `RESPFACT` column is the same in all rows, so it does not affect the rows being returned.

Comment: This is certainly not a CTE named ENCRYPTION.. ;) I think you missed a comma

Comment: @NickyvV . . . Thank you and Martin.  I have a default definition for `with` and didn't look hard enough in this case.